# Korean movie where the hero fights monsters to get his limbs back

Tags: story-identification, movie

Next to the studio where my daughter took ballet lessons (around 2011–2015), there was a shop where a guy sold second-hand clothing, bootleg DVDs, and other sundry goods. I sometimes went in to browse while my daughter was dancing, and he usually had one of his DVDs playing. There was one, in particular, that I remember making quite an impression on me—based purely on its visuals—that I might like to see again some time.  It was probably less than a decade old when I saw it, so from some time in this century.

The film was Korean (I think; it is conceivable that it might have been Japanese), with a standard eastern sword-and-sorcery setting.  I only saw about five minutes of the movie, but I asked the store owner what it was about, and this was what he told me:  The protagonist was a powerful fighter, but due to some kind of curse (or perhaps a deal he had once made with a demonic entity), most of his extremities had been replaced by artificial limbs. (I think they were made of wood.) He was now on quest to win the rest of his body back, by fighting a series of monsters.*

The one monster that I saw him fight was a sort of giant crab or insect, larger than a human. The battle took place indoors, in a chamber surrounded by drab wood paneling.

*The description definitely sounds like the live-action version of *[Dororo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dororo_(film))*, but I checked, and that was not the film I am looking for.  It is conceivable that the store owner, who was not watching the movie very closely and had evidently seen it before, had actually confused the film he had on with *Dororo* and gave me a description of *Dororo* instead of the actual film that was playing.  In that case though, there is probably little hope of me finding this actual film.  (And I have learned about *Dororo*, which is cool on its own.)

Comment: How old did that look?

Comment: What made you believe it was Korean, specifically? How the subtitles looked?

Comment: Even without knowing almost anything of either either language, it's not too hard to tell them apart:  Korean sentences will tend to end with the sound yo and Japanese sentences will tend to end with desu or masu.

Comment: @Adamant okay, I was thinking that might help get some more details.

Comment: @Stormblessed I don't honestly remember what it was that clued me in that it was Korean.  It might have been the subtitles, or the phonology, or the owner of the store might just have told me it was from Korea.

Comment: It might be a Chinese fantasy movie with Korean subtitles. Chinese make many movies with that type  genre

Comment: The story sounds like Dororo, but I don't recall a live action version, although TV Tropes says there was one that was in different setting. (the animes are set in Sengoku Japan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the movie is [*Dororo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dororo_(film)), it's based on a manga by Osamu Tesuka by the same name. It tells the history of Hyakkimaru, a boy who his father sold his first born son to 48 demons before his birth, each taking a part of his body. It's a Japanese movie, live-action adaptation from 2007.

Comment: Also, just this year there was a anime remake.